# Accessing the shared documents folder within a private group of a sharepoint site using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am in the process of trying to use Graph API to upload a test file to a Sharepoint site. I am struggling to correctly point Graph API to a point within the Shared Documents folder on a private group.

Suppose the host is devsite.sharepoint.com and the private group is "Development". In the shared documents there is a folder called "TestFolder".

[Private Group with folder "TestFolder"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpng1.png)

By trial and error on graph explorer, I've successfully navigated to the private group using.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/Development`

I've unsuccessfully tried to access the shared documents folder using the following

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/Development/drive/root`

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/Development/Shared%20Documents/TestFolder`

all of which return

`Code: BadRequestMessage: Url specified is invalid`
or
`The provided path does not exist, or does not represent a site`

The graph API website documentation, unfortunately, doesn't yield anything of value, any help on this from the crowd would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/Development:/drives` returns something like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2021-07-24T23:35:00Z",
            "description": "",
            "id": "b!A1234567-ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-08-12T16:39:23Z",
            "name": "Dokumente",
            "webUrl": "https://organizationname.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSIteName/folderName",
            "driveType": "documentLibrary",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "abc"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "bla@organizationame.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "12345678-4321-4321-4321-012345678901",
                    "displayName": "zz"
                }
            },
            "owner": {
                "group": {
                    "email": "x@y.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "09876543-1234-1234-1234-012345678901",
                    "displayName": "Owner of something"
                }
            },
            "quota": {
                "deleted": 345678,
                "remaining": 27487788453406,
                "state": "normal",
                "total": 27487790694400,
                "used": 96120
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `id` parameter under `description` in the above json is the `drive-id` of your shared documents folder. You can use it like this to access and navigate your shared documents folder:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com/drives/b!A1234567-ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210/root:/yourfile.docx
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - worked a treat. Before I mark it as a solution, is there a way this could be achieved without needing to use the `drive-id` and only using relative paths?

Ideally, I'd like the path to be self-documenting so another dev could understand without needing any further comments. Something like:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/devsite.sharepoint.com:/sites/Development:/drives/Documents/root:/TestFolder/test.txt`

Would this require the [special](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get-specialfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) keyword?

Comment: I spend long hours to research and solve exactly the problem that you are describing (for my own application). There appears to be no solution with relative paths only, at least not at this point in time. I was happy with the above solution, because although it requires an extra http request, it can still be automated if required.